# How can I fadeIn elements during a click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pug

More specifically, I want to fade one by one my `a` elements from my `mobile-container` when the transition of the `mobile-container` transitions stops when it's opened. [This](https://www.dtelepathy.com/) website has exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

[Here](https://codepen.io/make96/pen/jxVeeL) is a link to my codepen.

Bellow is my code.. without the Sass and Jquery files because the indentation on stack overflow is killing me.

Jade:

```
nav
 a(id='brand') ecostudent
 ul(class='main-navigation')
  li
   a lorem
  li
   a lorem
  li
   a lorem
  li
   a lorem 
 div(class='menu-wrapper')
  div(class='line-menu top')
  div(class='line-menu bottom')
 div(class='mobile-container')
  ul(class='mobile-navigation')
   li
    a lorem
   li
    a lorem
   li
    a lorem
   li
    a lorem
   div(class='menu-closing-wrapper')
    div(class='line-menu top')
    div(class='line-menu bottom')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transition-delay` combined with sass loops and completely avoid javascript:

```
@for $i from 0 through 3
  .mobile-container.active li:nth-child(#{$i})
    transition-delay: 330ms + (100ms * $i) !important
```

Check this [fork](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aGBPXL) of your codepen.

Comment: Yes! This is so cool.. Do you have any idea how can I fade in and slide down simultaneously my li elements using your solution?

Comment: @Marius Just add a transform property on the li items (I only added opacity).

Comment: I added transform: translateY(-10px) on the li from the mobile-container and transform: translateY(0) on the li from the mobile-container.active but the only thing that changes is the initial position of the li elements.
They don't slide down.
Edit:
I managed to make it work by adding !important at the end of transform: translateY(0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery plugin https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear/ to track elements when they appear and provide data animations based on it.

E.g. You can give your element and attribute data-animated="fadeIn" and the plugin will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is probably just to loop through each list item and create a setTimeout for a fade-in. My jquery is a little rusty but something like this:

```
$('.mobile-navigation li').each(function(index,item) {
    setTimeout( function(){$(item).fadeIn();}, index*100);
});
```